# "1 new answers" Pluralization bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

Bug: The page element bar that notifies the reader of new answers has an issue with pluralization.

[image]

**Edit (Lord_Farin):** While at it, please fix the similar issue with comments, as observed below [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/11493/43351).

Comment: These are `1` bugs. `I` likes your `1` questions `1` lots.

Comment: Watch out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/9694

Comment: @user103254: Since Jeff is no longer an employee of SE Inc., Arkamis should be safe. I hope?

Comment: @user103254 But that post clearly excludes me.

Comment: The language is the one that has a bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was a temporary glitch while we've been working on enabling localization of our javascript strings. This bug was present everywhere where javascript rendered something that needed pluralization logic.

Everything works normally again:

[image]